# How to migrate 1000 list items from List1 in Site1 to List2 in Site2 Using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, export, import

I'm using Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPExportSettings/SPImportSettings class to migrate 1 listitem successfully.

But I need to migrate only 1000 listitems.

Thanks in Advance:)

Comment: or any example to move 1 foder data using [Microsoft.SharePoint.Deployment.SPDeploymentObjectType]::Folder

Answer (score 0):

```
$GC = Start-SPAssignment 

$Site1= Get-SPWeb $UrlSite1
$Site2= Get-SPWeb $UrlSite2

$List1= $Site1.Lists["List1_Title"]
$List2= $Site2.Lists["List2_Title"]

//ListItem
foreach ($listItem in $List1.Items)
{
    $newItem = $List2.items.add()
    $newItem =  $listItem
    $newItem.Update()
}
//Folder
 foreach ($folderItem in $List1.Folders)
{

}


Stop-SPAssignment $GC
```